# How to create cascading dropdownlist?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am very new to MVC and need help regarding cascading dropdownlists. The purpose is to log a fault with  faulty equipment in a venue. I have two tables: "Venue" and "VenueEquipment". The first dropdown should be a list of venues and upon selection of a venue from the list, it should populate another dropdown with the various equipment types in the venue. I am assuming that a user can only log a fault with one type of equipment.

The code in my "FaultsController" is:

```
    // GET: Faults/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.UserID = new SelectList(db.UserTables, "UserID", "UserEMailAddress");
        ViewBag.VenueNum = new SelectList(db.VenueEquipmentTables, "VenueEquipmentID",                          "VenueNum");
        ViewBag.VenueEquipmentID = new SelectList(db.VenueEquipmentTables, "VenueEquipmentID", "VenueEquipmentType");

        return View();
    }
```

The code in my view is:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.VenueEquipmentID, "Venue Number", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("VenueNum", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.VenueEquipmentID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.VenueEquipmentID, "Venue Equipment Type", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("VenueEquipmentID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.VenueEquipmentID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

My Model -"FaultTable" is as follows:

```
public partial class FaultTable
{

    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public int VenueEquipmentID { get; set; }

    public virtual UserTable UserTable { get; set; }
    public virtual VenueEquipmentTable VenueEquipmentTable { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create separate action which returns the JSON for dependent dropdown, and then call the change event and inside that event call the action through jQuery and bind the other dropdown.

Some examples

1. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4d9083/creating-simple-cascading-dropdownlist-in-mvc-4-using-razor/
2. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/730953/Cascading-Dropdown-List-With-MVC-LINQ-to-SQL-and-A